# Extract the first 6 lines from nvarchar text and the rest

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, substring, sql-server-2016

I need to extract the first 6 lines from this text and then the rest with a select statment, im using SQL server 2016.

```
Hi,
this is an
example
text to
extract the
first 6 lines
and then extract 
the rest,
thanks
```

SELECT '6 first lines', 'rest lines'

Result:

COLUMN 1:

```
Hi,
this is an
example
text to
extract the
first 6 lines
```

Column 2:

```
and then extract
the rest,
thanks
```

Comment: What have you tried, why didn't it work? Is the delimiter CRLF, or just LF?

Comment: Where and how is "this text" stored in your database? Is in in a table wiith one row per newline? Is it an inline text copy-paste in a query window?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis It is stored in a nvarchar colum with char(13) line jumps

Comment: Just a carriage return, no line break (as well)?

Comment: It must have a line break. Also have you tried something?

Comment: I used the notepad to check it, it has CRLF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

browse for  DelimitedSplit8K

This is a table function that can split up any string by it's delimiter (in this case likely to be CHR(10) and/or CHR(13) into a table with a position number and the contents.  You can then select position <= 6 or > 6 for the two queries

Comment: `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD` is even better ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a recent version of SQL Server, you can use the built-in functions [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) and [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql). A `TABLE` variable is used with an `INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to keep track of the line numbers.

SQL Code:

```
CREATE TABLE Report (id INT, LongText NVARCHAR(MAX))
GO

INSERT INTO Report VALUES (37, 'Hi,
this is an
example
text to
extract the
first 6 lines
and then extract 
the rest,
thanks
')
GO

DECLARE @Splitted TABLE(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), value NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Splitted
       SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT( (SELECT TOP 1 LongText FROM Report WHERE id=37), CHAR(13) )

SELECT (SELECT STRING_AGG(value, CHAR(13)) FROM @Splitted WHERE id <= 6) AS Column_1,
       (SELECT STRING_AGG(value, CHAR(13)) FROM @Splitted WHERE id  > 6) AS Column_2

GO
DROP TABLE Report
```

You can see it working in a [SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6906057db5d61ea18bade42d4b7ffbe8)

*I had to use `CHAR(10)` in the Fiddle because of how linebreaks are represented there. Presumably caused by the Web interface or by Linux hosting.*

---

You can also create a **User Defined Function** for it:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION SplitAsColumns(@LongText NVARCHAR(MAX), @LineCount INT)
RETURNS @TABLE TABLE(Column_1 NVARCHAR(MAX), Column_2 NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Splitted TABLE(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), value NVARCHAR(MAX))
    INSERT INTO @Splitted SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT( @LongText, CHAR(13) )
    INSERT @TABLE
        SELECT (SELECT STRING_AGG(value, CHAR(13)) FROM @Splitted WHERE id <= @LineCount) AS Column_1,
               (SELECT STRING_AGG(value, CHAR(13)) FROM @Splitted WHERE id  > @LineCount) AS Column_2
    RETURN
END
GO

SELECT * FROM SplitAsColumns('Hi,
this is an
example
text to
extract the
first 6 lines
and then extract 
the rest,
thanks
', 6)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my SQL server version does not support STRING_AGG function

Comment: That's too bad. Best to always specify your SQL version in your question.